# How to send powermail forms without 404 error on subages with TYPO3 9.5?

Tags: url, path, typo3, typo3-9.x, powermail

I try to send a simple form at a subpage, but got a 404 error. The problem does not appear at the home page of my website so I guess there is something wrong with or missing in my `config.yaml` file.
Below is my `config.yaml`. Any idea anyone?

```
rootPageId: 1
base: 'http://www.my-domain.de/'
baseVariants:
  -
    base: 'http://www.my-domain.intern'
    condition: 'applicationContext == "Development"'
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: '4'
```

Comment: I assume you use Apache webserver. Can you navigate to the subpage using the menus? If not, maybe the `.htaccess` file is missing in your webroot?

Comment: Yes, Apache webserver with a .htaccess file - navigation is no problem. And I have got a configuration to enforce trailing slash (and ignore trailing slash on file endings). That may course the error... let me check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, bug found - thanks, Chris.
If I force the trailing slash in the `.htaccess`, I have to adjust my `config.yaml` accordingly. That's how it works.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # EXTRA: Enforce trailing slash. Ignore trailing slash on file endings
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|xml|rss|txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js|xml|rss|txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**config.yaml**

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: '/'
    suffix: '/'
    index: ''
    map:
      '/': 0
```